# compare 2 files and append a value from file1 to end of file2 after match

Tags: python, shell, awk

I have to match Column1 of FILE1 with values of FILE2 and if it matches, append Column3 from FILE1 to end of each line in FILE2.

I have included examples below and any help is appreciated.

FILE1

```
405869000009306,917010120346,3535080769880902
405869000013492,917010130771,8687780205056100
405869000014438,917010132781,8626280378318000
```

FILE2

```
9,=5|0|Pay,=,=,=1|1|918438953359,+918438953359@,=405869000009306,=20180304060000804+0530,=0,=0,=140,=0,=25,=0,=180304055956+22,=199,=1,=1,=-e-89-43-16-e367d-5a9b3e08-98b90,+918438953359@,=1|1|917019075052,=1|1|917010075000,=,=,=,=,=icid-value=14.137.67-1520123400.11094809;icid-generated-at;orig-ioi,



8,=1|1|918667657858,+918667657858@,=405869000013492,=1|1|919894455911,=,=,=20180304060000740+0530,=0,=1,=2,=0,=0,=0,=000000000000+00,=0,=1,=1,=1567756633_2338487864@2405:204:7a4e:2019:f339:d39b:1e12:915e,=sip:tn1ipsxm001.ims.mnc869.mcc405.3gppnetwork.org,=1|1|917010075000,=1|1|917010075009,mnc,=3GPP-E-UTRAN-FDD;405869006D039F831,=,=,=icid-value=11.274.6905-1520123400.57776869;icid-generated-at;orig-ioi,
```

OUTPUT

```
9,=5|0|Pay,=,=,=1|1|918438953359,+918438953359@,=405869000009306,=20180304060000804+0530,=0,=0,=140,=0,=25,=0,=180304055956+22,=199,=1,=1,=-e-89-43-16-e367d-5a9b3e08-98b90,+918438953359@,=1|1|917019075052,=1|1|917010075000,=,=,=,=,=icid-value=14.137.67-1520123400.11094809;icid-generated-at;orig-ioi,3535080769880902



8,=1|1|918667657858,+918667657858@,=405869000013492,=1|1|919894455911,=,=,=20180304060000740+0530,=0,=1,=2,=0,=0,=0,=000000000000+00,=0,=1,=1,=1567756633_2338487864@2405:204:7a4e:2019:f339:d39b:1e12:915e,=sip:tn1ipsxm001.ims.mnc869.mcc405.3gppnetwork.org,=1|1|917010075000,=1|1|917010075009,mnc,=3GPP-E-UTRAN-FDD;405869006D039F831,=,=,=icid-value=11.274.6905-1520123400.57776869;icid-generated-at;orig-ioi,8687780205056100
```

Comment: Please add the code of what you have tried

Comment: Note that your samples are not clear, please wrap your code in CODE TAGS.

Comment: i used this. but matched value not getting appended at end of each row.

Comment: awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$4; next}{print $0,a[$28]}' FILE1 FILE2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use the below code:

```
file1 = open("input1.txt","r")
file2 = open("input2.txt","r")

file2_array = [data for data in file2]

file = open("output.txt","a")
for row in file1:
    element_to_check = row.split(",")[0]
    for row_to_check in file2_array:
        if element_to_check in row_to_check:
            file.write('%s,%s'%(row_to_check, row.split(",")[2]) + '\n')
```

This code is reading from the two input files(i am assuming as text files) and then comparing the data and if the condition is satisfied, then it appends the code to the line and writes it to a output file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Subrajyoti Das , Waveter. Both scripts are working fine.

Comment: I am using awk and its failing...can you pls help to correct the command am using to get the similar output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the shell script below

```
#!/bin/bash
content1=`cat file1`
while read line2; do
        found=0
        for line1 in $content1; do
                first_column=`echo $line1|awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`
                if [[ $line2 = *"$first_column"* ]]; then
                        third_column=`echo $line1|awk -F ',' '{print $3}'`
                        echo $line2.$third_column
                        found=1
                        break
                fi
        done;
        if [[ $found == 0 ]]; then
                echo $line2;
        fi
done < file2
```

Comment: Hi , after running python script the column3 value gets added with an next line and another ",". I tried removing "," , but got syntax error..is there a way for this?

Comment: file.write('%s %s'%(row_to_check row.split(",")[2]) + '\n')
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: here is the output using python where value added with next line and extra comma.

Comment: 9,5|0|Pay,,,1|1|918438953359,+918438953359@,405869000009306,20180304060000804+0530,0,0,140,0,25,0,180304055956+22,199,1,1,-e-89-43-16-e367d-5a9b3e08-98b90,+918438953359@,1|1|917019075052,1|1|917010075000,,,,,icid-value14.137.67-1520123400.11094809;icid-generated-at;orig-ioi,
,3535080769880902

Comment: When i run shell script for file with 1000 of lines, i see that only 2 lines are executed and script hangs

Comment: I updated the script. It may be slow for the big file, but I don't think it hangs